# Let A and B be subspaces of $R^5$ such that A $ \subseteq$ B

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let A and B be subspaces of $R^5$ such that A $ \subseteq$ B.

$ \{a1,a2,a3\} $is a basis for subspace A.

$\{b1,b2,b3,b4\} $ is a linearly dependant set that spans B.

$ \quad $  (1) Dimension of B = 4

$ \quad $ (2) A = B

$ \quad $ (3) $\{b1,b2,b3,b4\}$ is a basis for B.

$ \quad $ (4) Dimension of A = 3

I think that **only (4)** would be true, **(1) and (3) are untrue** because the vectors $b_i$ are linearly dependent, but I am not sure if there is a way to prove that **B $\subseteq$ A, which would make (2) true**? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1 is false. The $b$ vectors are linearly dependent and span $B$, so you could remove one and still span $B$, so you could span $B$ with less than 4 vectors, so dimension is less than 4.

3 is also false given the same logic as for 1)

4 is true because 3 vectors form a basis of A.

Now, note that since A is a subset of B, B must be dimension 3. Any 3 linearly independent vectors in B then are a basis of B. The $a$ vectors are linearly independent and in B, and there are 3 of them, so they are also a basis for B. Therefore A and B share a basis, so $A = B$, so 2 is true.

Remember the rules for a list of vectors being a basis: Must have two out of three of the following:

- Spanning
- Linearly independent
- List length the same as the dimension of the space

If you have two, the other one is always implied.

TL;DR 2 and 4 are true, 1 and 3 are false, but do try to understand the reasoning why

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong that only $4)$ has to be true, (which it is since the dimension is the number of elements in a basis).  There is  a way to deduce that $B\subset A$:  since the $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ are dependent, it follows that $\rm{dim}B=3$.  Thus $2)$ is also true.

Answer (score 0):

Some very important facts about spanning sets and linearly independent sets (in finite dimensional spaces) are

1. *A spanning set has at least as many elements as any linearly independent set.*
2. *Any spanning set contains a basis.*
3. *Any linearly independent set of vectors that has as many elements as the dimension is a basis.*

You're given that $B$ has dimension at least $3$, because it contains the linearly independent set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$. The dimension of $B$ can therefore be at most $4$, because it has a spanning set with four elements and we can apply fact 1.

However, you're also given that this spanning set is *linearly dependent*, so the basis it contains (fact 2) cannot be the whole set. It follows that the dimension of $B$ is at most $3$.

Hence the dimension of $B$ is exactly $3$. Apply fact 3 to $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$, which is a linearly independent set in $B$ to conclude that $A=B$.